# How to add column names to 2d array when printing with console.table() javascript

Tags: javascript

If I have a 2d array like this...

```
var x = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 1, 2]
]
```

And I want to print it to the console using `console.table()` but I also want to add column names, how do I do that?

I see in the documentation its really easy when its an array of objects, but when I try to add column names to this 2d array it messes with the array dimensions and does not print correctly.

EDIT:
All of the answers this far have said what I said I already knew, that this was easy to do with an array of objects. My question is, "Is it possible to add column names if you are passing a 2d array."

Answer (score 0):

I tried to console.table with your 2d array compare with array of object, Hope this is what you looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array of objects to `console.table()` in order for it to display with column names, exammple below using your data:

```js
const arrayOfObjects = new Array(10).fill({
  columnOne : 0,
  columnTwo: 1,
  columnThree: 2
})

console.table(arrayOfObjects)
```

Here is a screenshot directly from the Developer Tools Console in Chrome.

[image: Example of this code]

More info can be found here regarding this function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table

Answer (score 0):

If the array contains objects, then the columns are labeled with the property name.
So you can convert the elements to objects with relevant names as properties.

```js
var x = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 1, 2]
]

function ARR(first, second, third) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    this.third = third;
}

let itemArr = x.map( item => new ARR(...item))

console.table(itemArr);
```

[image: Sample Output]